# How to connect MS Access database with Java 8?

Tags: java, ucanaccess

**What I am trying to do:**

I want to connect my MS Access Database with Java 8. So I am using "UcanAccess" driver to connect to my Database.

**What I am using:**

Eclipse, Java 8, and MS Access database

**My MS Access database path**:

```
C:/Users/dave/My_WorkSpace/Eclipse_Workspaces/workspace-jsp/Database11.accdb"
```

**I have the following Jar files in my project:**

- mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar
- ucanaccess-2.095.jar
- jackcess-2.1.2.jar
- hsqldb.jar
- commons-lang3-3.4.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar

**Error**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.RowIdImpl.compareTo(RowIdImpl.java:106)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$Entry.compareTo(IndexData.java:2039)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$Entry.compareTo(IndexData.java:1847)
at java.util.Collections.indexedBinarySearch(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.binarySearch(Unknown Source)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$DataPage.findEntry(IndexData.java:2570)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData.findEntryPosition(IndexData.java:844)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData.access$3700(IndexData.java:47)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.updatePosition(IndexData.java:2335)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.restorePosition(IndexData.java:2273)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.restorePosition(IndexData.java:2256)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.beforeEntry(IndexData.java:2218)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexCursorImpl.findPotentialRow(IndexCursorImpl.java:376)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexCursorImpl.findFirstRowByEntryImpl(IndexCursorImpl.java:282)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexCursorImpl.findFirstRowByEntry(IndexCursorImpl.java:153)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl$DefaultTableFinder.findRow(DatabaseImpl.java:2074)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl$TableFinder.findObjectId(DatabaseImpl.java:1953)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.readSystemCatalog(DatabaseImpl.java:858)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.<init>(DatabaseImpl.java:518)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:389)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:248)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DefaultJackcessOpener.open(DefaultJackcessOpener.java:38)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.<init>(DBReference.java:158)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReferenceSingleton.loadReference(DBReferenceSingleton.java:57)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:103)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at ex01.main(ex01.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.builder.CompareToBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 28 more
```

**code to connect to database:**

```
public class ex01 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/dave/My_WorkSpace/Eclipse_Workspaces/workspace-jsp/Database11.accdb";

    Connection con;

    Statement stmt;

    String query = "Select * from user";

    try {
        // Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");

        stmt = con.createStatement();

        // Returns a ResultSet that contains the data produced by the query;
        // never null
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        System.out.println("User Data:");
        System.out.println("FirstName\tLastName\tAge");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String fName = rs.getString("FirstName");
            String lName = rs.getString("LastName");
            int age = rs.getInt("age");
            System.out.println(fName + "\t" + lName + "\t" + age);
        }

        stmt.close();

        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try with version 2.0 (commons-lang-2.0.jar) of `commons-lang` jar.

Comment: I guess, there is some **mismatch** in your JARs, check below article for complete example with driver & dependent JARs information http://www.benchresources.net/jdbc-msaccess-database-connection-steps-in-java-8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [you can see](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.healthmarketscience.jackcess/jackcess/2.1.2), jackcess 2.1.2 depends on commons-lang 2.6. The version you use (3.4) is not backward compatible.

Why do you have a JDBC driver for MySQL and for HSQLDB if your goal is to connect to MS Access?

Comment: Great link. Old version is for backword compatibility.

Comment: The [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver for Access databases uses HSQLDB as a backing database (usually in-memory only).